# luabind 0.9.1 iterator always only pop the last object

Tags: c++, luabind

all. I got a stranger problem by using luabind to read a array from lua script.

The lua script looks like this:

```
root = 
{
        id = 1,
        id = 2,
        id = 3
};
```

and the c++ code is looks like this:
    luabind::object data_root = luabind::globals(L)["root"];

```
for (luabind::iterator i(data_root), end; i != end; ++i)
{
    luabind::object data = *i;
    unsigned int id = luabind::object_cast<unsigned int>(data);
    std::cout << "id:" << id << std::endl;
}
```

the output is only:

```
id:3
```

I want to output all the elements of the [root], but it only output the last one and over.

Thank You, Jason :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't multiple elements of root, it only has one. You assigned the key `id` to three different values, but the key only exists once and only has one value associated with it, so you basically only ever said `root = { id = 3 }`.